# Miranda Type error

Tags: haskell, partial-application, miranda

Can anyone tell me where goes wrong?

```
b f x = f x (f x)
```

My understanding is: because `f` at the left takes one argument but on the right side it has two arguments?

Any more detail explanations?

Comment: `f` does not "take arguments on the left side". The `x` is not an argument to `f` in the LHS.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to construct that type:

```
b :: ... ?
```

We have at least two arguments, so lets change `b` accordingly:

```
b :: a -> c -> d
```

The right hand side of `b` suggests that `f` is a function. Lets first concern only the first argument:

```
f :: c -> e
```

Up till now, everything fits quite nice: the first argument of list has the same type as the second argument of b. Lets continue on the right hand side.

```
f x (f x)
```

If we take `f x _`, we have to assume that `e` is `e :: k -> l`, that is, we take another argument. We now have

```
f :: c -> k -> l
```

Now have a look at the type of `f`'s second argument. It's type should be the one of `f x`:

```
f x :: k -> l
```

So `k = k -> l`. That's an infinite type, which we can also see by looking at ghci's error message:

```
Prelude> let b f x = f x (f x)

<interactive>:2:18:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t1 = t1 -> t0
    In the return type of a call of `f'
    Probable cause: `f' is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of `f', namely `(f x)'
    In the expression: f x (f x)
```

The type checker gives up, as infinite type cannot be constructed by it. At the end, this happens since you apply `f` on a different number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler tries to infer the type of `f`.  First it sees that `f` takes an argument `x` and another argument `(f x)`, which for now we'll substitute as `y`.  So when the compiler sees something like `f x y`, it infers that `f` has the type `a -> b -> c`, with `x :: a`, `y :: b`, and `f x y :: c`.  Then it inspects `y` closer, seeing that its type is more specifically `b -> c`, since it already knows `f` must have a second argument.  So it can now determine that `b ~ b -> c`.  And this is where it has to stop, how can `b` also be `b -> c`?  If it kept substituting `b ~ b -> c`, it would have an infinite recursion trying to figure out what type `b` is!  This obviously can't work, so it throws a compile error saying that it can't construct the infinite type `b = b -> c` (note: the error message may use different names than `b` or `c`).  The error message I get is actually pretty helpful:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t1 = t1 -> t0
In the return type of a call of `f'
Probable cause: `f' is applied to too few arguments
In the second argument of `f', namely `(f x)'
In the expression: f x (f x)
```

This tells you exactly where the problem is, "namely `(f x)`", and gives you the probable cause "`f` is applied to too few arguments", saying that it "cannot construct the infinite type `t1 = t1 -> t0`".